# Add new classes or resources in the .apk application file at runtime

Tags: apk, dex

I'm working on a project, one of the task of this project leads me to find a way to modify the apk file of an android application, adding or removing resources from it. I find a useful library called "dextranslator" but I need to know if it's possible to do such task during the execution of the application...I thought to stop temporary the application, modify the dex file inside the apk and restart it. Is there any existing lib that can helps me or I have to find a way by my self?